# SQL query: Where and like statments

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I'm trying to make a query to get the results that have null in one of their columns but for for some reason when I use `like` the part where I exclude the not null fields doesnt work

```
SELECT * FROM my_column WHERE title LIKE "%hea%" OR department LIKE "%hea%" OR title_pt LIKE "%hea%" AND deleted_at IS NULL LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parenthesis

```
SELECT * FROM my_column WHERE (title LIKE "%hea%" OR department LIKE "%hea%" OR
title_pt LIKE "%hea%") AND deleted_at IS NULL LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Think of it like math, you have to tell it the order of operation. You were actually asking for `title_py LIKE "%hea" AND deleted_at IS NULL` while the other `OR`s were not interacting with the `AND` at all.

Answer (score 1):

you wrote this :

```
SELECT * FROM my_column 
 WHERE (title LIKE "%hea%") OR (department LIKE "%hea%") 
    OR ((title_pt LIKE "%hea%") AND (deleted_at IS NULL)) 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

You wanted this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_column 
 WHERE ((title LIKE "%hea%") OR (department LIKE "%hea%") OR (title_pt LIKE "%hea%")) 
   AND (deleted_at IS NULL) 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The parenthesis will give you ONLY the rows with `deleted_at` NULL AND one of the other conditions TRUE:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_column 
WHERE (   
          title      LIKE "%hea%" 
       OR department LIKE "%hea%" 
       OR title_pt   LIKE "%hea%"
      )
      AND 
          deleted_at IS NULL 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```